# One object moves along the cycloid at a constant rate, how about its acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, vectors, differentiation

We know that the parametric equation:

$$x=R(\theta+\sin(\theta))$$

$$y=-R(1+\cos(\theta))$$

and the constant velocity $c$.

How do I prove that the acceleration of the object in the $y$ direction is constant?

OK, this is not just a simple homework question, I want to learn something about mathematical physics from this question. I am suffered from $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$:why can't I get the second derivation of parametric equations $y=-R(1+\cos(\theta))$ , which gives the solution related to $\theta$?

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Also, I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} 
\newcommand{\e}{\bl=}
\newcommand{\p}{\bl+}
\newcommand{\m}{\bl-}
\newcommand{\gr}{\bl>}
\newcommand{\les}{\bl<}
\newcommand{\greq}{\bl\ge}
\newcommand{\leseq}{\bl\le}
\newcommand{\plr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\blr}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\lara}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\lav}[1]{\langle#1|}
\newcommand{\vra}[1]{|#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavra}[2]{\langle#1|#2\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavvra}[3]{\langle#1|\,#2\,|#3\rangle}
\newcommand{\vp}{\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\newcommand{\hp}[1]{\hphantom{#1}} 
\newcommand{\x}{\bl\times}
\newcommand{\qqlraqq}{\qquad\bl{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}\qquad}
\newcommand{\qqLraqq}{\qquad\boldsymbol{\e\!\e\!\e\!\e\!\Longrightarrow}\qquad}
%----------------------------$

First we use the following parametric equation of cycloid
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x & \e R\plr{\theta\m\sin\theta}\\
y & \e R\plr{1\m\cos\theta}\\
\end{split} 
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}
The velocity vector is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf v\e c\plr{\cos\phi,\sin\phi}
\tag{02}\label{02}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\tan\phi\e\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\e\dfrac{\sin\theta}{1\m\cos\theta}\e \cot\plr{\cdots}
\tag{03}\label{03}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\mathbf v\e c\blr{\sin\plr\cdots,\cos\plr\cdots}
\tag{04}\label{04}
\end{equation}
For  the acceleration vector $\:\mathbf a\:$ we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbf a\e\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf v}{\mathrm dt}\e\cdots\:\dot{\!\!\theta}\left(\cdots,\cdots\right)
\tag{05}\label{05}
\end{equation}
But
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
c\e & \dfrac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}\e\sqrt{1\p\left(\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2}\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\\
& \e\cdots\cdots\cdots\e \cdots\cdots\cdots\:\dot{\!\!\theta}\\
\end{split} 
\tag{06}\label{06}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\dot{\!\!\theta}\e \dfrac{c}{\cdots\cdots}
\tag{07}\label{07}
\end{equation}
Inserting this expression in equation \eqref{05} we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbf a\e\left(\mathrm a_{\,x},\mathrm a_{\,y}\right)
\tag{08}\label{08}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
a_{\,y}\e\cdots\e\texttt{constant ???}
\tag{09}\label{09}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

To find $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$ in the case where the speed along the cycloid is constant, using $\omega$ for $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$, the formulae in the question and using the chain rule $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{d\theta}\times \frac{d\theta}{dt}$

the speed is constant $v_x^2 +v_y^2 = 2\omega^2R^2(1+\cos\theta) = c^2$

so $$\omega^2 = \frac{c^2}{2R^2(1+\cos\theta)}\tag1$$

so $$2\omega\frac{d\omega}{dt} = \frac{c^2}{2R^2} \times \frac{sin\theta}{(1+\cos\theta)^2}\times \omega \tag2$$

and $\frac{d\omega}{dt}$ can be found in terms of $\theta$

best of luck with it.

Comment: @ Frobenius, but the object oscillates up and down, surely that needs acceleration up and then acceleration down, so it doesn't seem as though it can be constant in the $y$ direction.

Comment: @ Frobenius even so the $y$ acceleration alternates up to down, however it isn't clear what $c$ means, presumably the velocity of the wheel, or perhaps that's the same anyway as the average speed of the object.  Then the magnitude of the total acceleration is constant at $\frac{c^2}{R}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have got the answer just like@Frobenius has gived by converting the parametric equation to the cartesian equation

Comment: @Frobenius you are right, but could you write the steps?

Comment: @JohnHunter your idea is not wrong, but it seems like the derivative has some troubles

Comment: @Joy, yes Frobenius was right that 1) is wrong as $ θ˙≠constant$, but 2) is right and maybe useful, so as it's a homework case, maybe you could take it from there, if I get time I'll try and correct the answer

Comment: @ Joy it's been improved, hopefully those hints might help